# jQuery Mobile: make a collapsible element 100% width/NOT inset

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, collapsable

Is there a way to make a collapsible element/set in jQuery Mobile not inset? By default it makes the collapsible element as an inset item.

`data-inset="false"` does not alter the behavior.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour? If it's about style you could restyle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you give the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties a negative value you can expand the collapsible content to the width of the page.

The default `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` values for a collapsible are `8px` so we can write a CSS rule for this:

```
.ui-collapsible {
    margin : 8px -15px;
}
```

I chose `-15px` because that is the negative amount of `padding` that the `data-role="content"` element adds to each page.

Here is a jsfiddle to view what this does: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/zSvqU/